# Trying to get property of non-object (using Carbon in Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5.3, php-carbon

I got this query `$paid_at = $invoice->payments->last()->paid_at` which works just fine, returning a **string** with a date "2013-04-04" (*dd*, *var_dump*, *print_r* confirmed it). But when I feed it to *Carbon* `$paid = new Carbon($paid_at);`I suddenly get this error:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
>
> Trying to get property of non-object

`$paid = new Carbon("2013-04-04");` works just fine too... Same with *\DateTime*.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

In your `payment` class add following property-

```
protected $dates = [
    'paid_at',
];
```

It will convert the `paid_at` column to instances of `Carbon` automatically.

And then you can run -

```
$invoice->payments->last()->paid_at; // returns instances of Carbon
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I really need to get to the bottom of this issue. Why is this happening?